# Метод "глубокой" копии в Java

Tags: java

Что почитать для того, чтобы понять как создать метод "глубокой" копии в Java.

Answer (score 1):

Существует несколько методов копирования классов

1. Через конструктор

   ```
   class MyObject {
     public MyObject(MyObject source) {
       this.setField1(..)
       return this;
     } 

     private string field1;
      .....
     public string setField1() { ... }
   }

   MyObject original = new MyObject(original);
   MyObject copy = new MyObject(original);
   ```
2. через реализацию интерфейса Cloneable

   ```
   @Override
   public Object clone() {
    try {
         return (MyObject) super.clone();
     } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
         return new MyObject(this);
     }
   }
   ```
3. Десериализация и сериализация. Для этого метода можно воспользоваться библиотеками
   google gson, apache commons lang, jackson

подробно с примерами можно посмотреть [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/java-deep-copy)